# Raw vs Unique pointers in the list

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Let's say I have std::list of some class T.

What is the best way to manage these elements? Considering that only the manager(I mean - the one owner) can add or remove items from the list.

1)

```
std::list < T* > myList;

//adding the new element
myList.push_back( new T(..) );

//deleting the one element
...roaming through the list...got it...
delete *iterator;
myList.erase(iterator);
```

2)

```
std::list < std::unique_ptr<T> > myList;

//adding the new element
myList.push_back ( std::unique_ptr<T>( new T(..) );

//deleting the one element
...roaming through the list...got it...
myList.erase(iterator);
```

Comment: "depends" is a good answer, but I would go with2 in most cases. Move sematics will do all the deleting for you, which is just a pain in the butt otherwise.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::list<T>`?

Comment: Do you need to store pointers (for polymorphism, perhaps)? If not, `std::list<T>` would be better still.

Comment: Anytime you need to dynamically allocate memory, you have to
define a policy concerning the lifetime of the objects.  If
`std::unique_ptr` fulfills the requirements of the policy, it's
great.  If it doesn't, don't use it.  I find it hard to imagine
a case where an `std::unique_ptr` would be appropriate in
a container, but I'm sure that there are cases.  (Containers are
designed to contains _copies_ of objects.  And `std::unique_ptr`
has rather special copy semantics.  Having said that, there is
at least one time in the past where I would have used it, had it
been available.)

Comment: When I tried to use std::list<T>, in particular: myList.push_back ( T() ); I saw there was created a new object using copy constructor. I felt it was bad

Comment: @MikeSeymour It kinda depends whether or not T has move semantics and/or the copy constructor of T is expensive and/or T is noncopyable, but I agree with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ownership model in your program is that the list "owns" the elements inside it, the second way (i.e. with `unique_ptr<T>`) is better. It lets C++ manage the resources of your list automatically, which is especially important in situations when the list is declared in a local scope, because you do not have to worry about exiting the scope prematurely.

Comment: What if I need to delete my object right now? What about garbage c. in this case?

Comment: @AlexeyTeplyakov If you must delete an object inside the list without touching the list, it means that your ownership model is different from "the list owns objects inside it"; if the list truly owns its objects as the use of `unique_ptr<T>` suggests, deleting an object should be performed by erasing its `unique_ptr<T>` from the list. Also note that "plain" pointers do not give you advantage or disadvantage in case when you must delete an object.

Comment: You got me wrong. Will there be a delay in the removal using garbage collector? In case of unique ptr

Comment: @AlexeyTeplyakov There is no garbage collector in C++ - `unique_ptr<T>` calls the destructor of the object that it points to as soon as the destructor of `unique_ptr<T>` itself is called. There is no delay there - when you erase an object (in this case `unique_ptr<T>`) from the list, the list destroys that object before `erase()` returns.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer. I'm talking nonsense. I thought for some reasons that it is the same way of deleting unique_ptr as deleting shared_ptr.

Comment: @AlexeyTeplyakov Causing a unique_ptr to go out of scope isn't any different than causing the last shared_ptr to an object to go out of scope.  When the last shared_ptr goes out of scope, the same thing happens.  The object is immediately deleted.

Answer (score 3):

In the words of [Herb Sutter's GotW column](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/):

> Guideline: To allocate an object, prefer to write make_unique by
>   default, and write make_shared when you know the object’s lifetime is
>   going to be managed by using shared_ptrs.

```
std::list < std::unique_ptr<T> > myList;

//adding the new element
myList.push_back ( std::make_unique<T>(..) );

//deleting the one element
...roaming through the list...got it...
myList.erase(iterator);
```

You can use Stephan T. Lavavej's [accepted C+14 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3588.txt) for the std::make_unique implementation.

Comment: 1) Is there a std::make_unique in c++11 ?
2) What if I need to delete my object right now? What about garbage c. in this case?

Comment: @AlexeyTeplyakov: No; hopefully that will be in C++14.

Comment: @AlexeyTeplyakov removing the pointer from the container will call the destructor of the element pointed to. There is no need for "naked" delete.